# Make bootstrap cols square

Tags: sass, bootstrap-sass

I have an index view in my Rails app. I want to display album covers in a title pattern in my index view with no gaps. I want the bootstrap divs with the class of "col-sm-4" to be the exact same height as their width, aka I want them to be squares. Is there a way to tie a div's height to its width without using javascript? I need it be responsive, obviously, because the width is responsive. I've searched around and can't seem to find an answer.

This is my code:

```
<%= @albums.each do |f| %>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <p><%= f.title %></p>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where is your (not-)Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: I have not started with any CSS yet. I want to solve this problem before further styling because everything else relies on it. Right now, the class you see is all there is. I want that width to be the divs height. I will obviously create a class for the new styles.

Comment: SO is not a place where you can just _ask_ for code, you have to try it first yourself. Please add a starting point in code to get a proper and quick answer to your question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You need set same width and height in parrent container.
Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
}

.container div {
  background:#555;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 33%;
}
```